# Select all headings through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to achieve what the "Select all instances" option does upon right clicking a Heading style. Recording a macro while clicking the button returns nothing.
The problem I am trying to solve is that when I paste a document into another one, the numbering of the headings do not update, even though the style is the same. This is fixed when I manually select the heading and click on its style again.

I have found this code:

```
docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
```

But it only gives a string list of what each header contains, therefore I would have to do additional loops to find these in the document and reapply their styles.

Is there any other way to select or loop through the headings of each style in the document to update their numberings?
Is there perhaps another approach to solve the initial problem of the numberings not updating in the first place?

Comment: You can use Find and Replace to find all content in a given style and replace it with the same style.

Comment: A print preview of the document via VBA should solve that.

Comment: I have not noticed until now, but as a last step in my code I make the user save the document in standard .docx format and close the .docm without saving so it can be reused for creating new documents again. The newly saved .docx had the heading numbers in a correct order already.